# JList MouseMoved and MousePressed

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouse, jlist

I've extended a `JList` to provide two separate functionalities, toolTipText for items, and right-click options. Both work separately, but when I try to use them together, the `MouseMoved` events aren't being recognized? Below are the guts of my new listener methods.  How should I be negotiating these various events?

```
public class JListTT extends javax.swing.JList {
    public JListTT() {
        super();
       addMouseListener(new ttListener());
...
   class ttListener extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
             String nodeID = bldItemNodeID();
             theList.setToolTipText(nodeID);
            }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent ev)  {check(ev); }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent ev) {check(ev); }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev)  {check(ev); }
        public void check(MouseEvent ev) {
            if (ev.isPopupTrigger()) { 
                theList.setSelectedIndex(theList.locationToIndex(ev.getPoint())); 
                menu.show(theList, ev.getX(), ev.getY()); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: @Dave Clemmer please for why **** you cleanup one of tag,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add the ttListener object as a MouseListener, but I don't see you adding the ttListener object as a MouseMotionListener.  For example:

```
ttListener myMouseadapter = new ttListener();
addMouseListener(myMouseadapter);
addMouseMotionListener(myMouseadapter);
```

Comment: i had thought adding a single addMouseListener(new ttListener()) would accomplish it for both addMouseListener and addMouseMotionListener subtypes, but i guess not cuz this works!  thanks much.

Comment: @rikb: yes, a MouseListener only listens for static mouse actions -- mousePress, mouseRelease, mouseClick, etc, whereas a MouseMotionListener will listen for dynamic mouse events. And you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I did not test this myself, but looking at the javadoc of `JList` the tooltip functionality is available out of the box. The javadoc of [JList#getTooltipText](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getToolTipText%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) clearly states

> Overrides JComponent's getToolTipText method in order to allow the
>   renderer's tips to be used if it has text set.

So if your `ListCellRenderer` returns a `Component` in the `getListCellRendererComponent` method which has a [tooltip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getToolTipText%28%29) it will be displayed by the `JList` without the need of a listener.

Answer (score 1):

there's not necessarily a need for a low-level approach as a custom mouse-/motionListener:

- as to a per-cell tooltip, see @Robin's answer
- as to a context menu, JComonent has a property componentPopupMenu: using that will cope with opening the menu on keyboard short-cut automatically

"not necessarily" because you seem to rely on the cell being selected on right click. If so, you would still need a MouseListener to trigger the selection (after decade long debates, Swing doesn't - which seems to be unusual in current native apps ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using **mouseDragged**

```
YourClass extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    ......

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        //code go here

    }
}
```